# orafce for postgresql version 10.1 undefined symbol: Float8GetDatum

Tags: postgresql, orafce

I'm trying to install orafce extension on postgresql 10.1. I'm getting the next error : Could not load library "$libdir/orafce": ERROR:  could not load library "MyPATH/orafce.so": MyPATH/orafce.so: undefined symbol: Float8GetDatum

When I run make install I dont get any errors. This is part of upgrade of postgreqsl 9.6.3 to 10.1. I got the error when I run pg_upgrade --check

Any idea what can I check ?

Comment: That sounds like you built orafce against a PostgreSQL installation that is configured different from the PostgreSQL where you are running it. Please share the details of how you built orafce.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by rebuilding the extension both on the old and on the new version (in that order).